# How do I install BlackDuck on mac?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, devsecops

I am trying to scan container images using the blackdock scanning tool. Unfortunately, I couldn't find any free version to play around with; please provide guidance and the simplest way to scan the docker images.

I have tried using this resource - https://github.com/blackducksoftware?q=docker&type=all&language=&sort=. Not able to install it.

Comment: Please provide details about the link you have posted, also include what you have already tried and what happened when you tried to install "it".

Answer (score 0):

Your link directs to a public GitHub org. It would also appear that their repositories are licensed under Apache 2.0 so you should be able to use these more or less how you see fit (obviously within Apache 2.0, but that is quite permissible). This is further bolstered on their website by their statement here [Introduction to Detect](https://community.synopsys.com/s/document-item?bundleId=integrations-detect&topicId=introduction.html&_LANG=enus) where they state:

> "...It is available through GitHub, under the permissive Apache License, Version 2.0 and does not require pre-installation or configuration."

Looks like you should be able to just pull down the repo and get cracking.